# Andegine or unity

Tags: android, game-engine

I'm new to android but I've been planning to create some basic game.I would like to jump in game development. I've seen many tutorials on how to create a game using andengine. But while searching for other tutorials, I've come across UNITY. And it supports android and IOS too. The other was monogame which you can create android game using c sharp? My question is, which is better to learn game developing for beginners? IS it UNITY or andengine or monogame? Please tell me your opinion.I need a guide here on where should i start? I really want to create android game and want to master it.

Comment: its better to ask ur question here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AndEngine will offer the best Android specific features. Unity will allow for easier porting across platforms.

However, as you have stated that you are new to Android, you shouldn't really be trying to make a game right now. Instead, you should spend at least 4-6 months learning Android, OpenGL and some game specific concepts before trying to make a game.

Comment: If im right studying opengl is like studying games right?

Comment: Why the downvote? OpenGL can be used to make games, but it is not the same as knowing game concepts and practices. It is a means to an end, and how you use it depends on your knowledge of Game Dev.

Comment: Im not the one who downvote.. I realy dont understand why other PROs here love to downvote everything.. haha.. Thanks.. i should study opengl then..

Comment: Im  sorry i cnt upvote cause i only have 13 rep.. 2 more and i can upvote y

Comment: Taking on a project is often the best way to learn.  And approaching too many new concepts at once often leads to messes and frustration.  Also, OpenGL is only necessary to learn if you're planning on pushing graphical boundaries— if one just wants to make a game, it's not necessary to know at all.  It can help to know some basics of it, especially towards e end of a project— but an approach of “just keep your tris, RAM, and draw calls down” suffices for most simple games.